# Whether to use: var app = angular.module... or simply: angular.module(

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and am working through various tutorials (Codecademy, thinkster.io and so on) and have seen two ways of declaring the app container. Firstly:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
```

Or simply like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
```

Is one better practice over the other or is it simply a different style without any major effect?

Comment: Different style... you can use `app` now to declare other things, like `app.controller` - of course you can always chain it: `angular.module("myApp, []).controller()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There'n no difference in how both the approach works except following

`var app = angular.module('myApp', [])` will add an extra *global* variable(If you're *hyper* conscious about global variables), however this will shorten your code, don't have to repeat `angular.module('myApp')` multiple times. You can use `app` instead of `angular.module('myApp').xxx` at many times.

You can chain the methods as follow, instead of adding a variable

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller(.....)
    .directive(.....)
    .factory(.....);
```

Comment: Also, you should know that when you pass an array as a second parameter (even if it's empty), you are **creating** a module. And you probably want to retrieve the module that has already been defined elsewhere. Read John Papa's [Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#modules) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

`angular.module` supports a third parameter, config function. If you chain you can do more than one config, which may be useful if you have a lot of configurations.

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .config(function(injectables) {
        //config block 1
    })
    .config(function(injectables) {
        //config block 2
    });
```

Instead of:

```
angular.module('myModule', [], function(){
    //only config
});
```

Also it eliminates risk of creating global variables when creating providers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, only the style and whatever you prefer, see this

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller("xCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
   }])
   .controller("yCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
   }])
  .controller("zCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
   }]);
```

In this case if you put the ; after y controll, z controller will not work. Means all will be treated as a single function. On the other way:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("xCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
}]);

app.controller("yCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
}]);

app.controller("zCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
}]);
```

In it every function is independent.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for setting a global variable referring to your module, is if you want to separate it in to multiple files.

for example:

**main.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('controller1',.....)
.controller('controller2',.....);
```

**directives.js**

```
app
.directive('directive1',.....)
.directive('directive2',.....);
```

although,you should know it is not so good to relay on global variables (`app` is global in this example), because they could get overridden by other librarys, and there are other ways to refer to your module in other files, like in this example:

**main.js:**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('controller1',.....)
.controller('controller2',.....);
```

**directives.js**

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('directive1',.....)
.directive('directive2',.....);
```

and if it is a big and complex angular application, you might even want to separate it to multiple modules:

**main.js:**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.directives'])
.controller('controller1',.....)
.controller('controller2',.....);
```

**directives.js**

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', [])
.directive('directive1',.....)
.directive('directive2',.....);
```